# Uso da biblioteca em S.O diferente

Tags: c, linux, windows, biblioteca

Galera,venha desenvolvendo alguns projetinhos em C porém em determinado momento houve a necessidade de utilizar a biblioteca "Windows.h". Até aí tudo bem,o problema é que desenvolvo com Linux e pesquisei sobre a biblioteca ela é exclusiva do Windows e obviamente não tem lógica utilizar no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma similiar para o Linux.

Comment: Sim, você aprendeu corretamente, o que é exclusivo para o Windows não serve para o Linux. Se vai usar API exclusiva de um sistema operacional use ela, não tente usar no outro. Existem outras APIs no Linux, totalmente diferentes, você tem que aprendê-las, não transpor o que tinha em uma para a outra.

Comment: Não existe magia, cada coisa tem de ser convertida manualmente, e algumas coisas ficam mesmo diferentes pois não tem correspondência direta. É por esse motivo que fazer um *port* de um sistema para outro é coisa complicada e que leva bastante tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim Eric, há bibliotecas similares:

Você pode optar em usar a GTK+ (https://www.gtk.org/), com ela você pode usar o mesmo código para desenvolver interfaces gráficas para Windows, Linux ou macOS, aqui tem uma lista das linguagens que a GTK suporta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_bindings_for_GTK%2B.

Você pode também escolher a Qt (https://www.qt.io/), não posso falar muito dela pois nunca a usei, mas o que ouvir falar é que diferente da GTK+ (que suporta C), esta oferece suporte para C++ ao invés de C.

Comment: Grato pelas informações,mano!. Muito útil.